# no suitable method found for getAnnotation(Class<CAP#1>)

Tags: java, class, generics, annotations, field

I'm coding a few simple methods to get annotations a class, field, or method.  The first method, which gets a class-level annotation, works fine.  Copy and paste that to create a new method to get a field-level annotation results in a compile error saying:

```
error: no suitable method found for getAnnotation(Class<CAP#1>)
```

Not sure how the getAnnotation method call on the Class object works OK but the same method call on the Field object results in this compilation error.

Thoughts?

```
public class AnnotationTool {
    public static <T> T getAnnotation(Class c, Class<? extends T> annotation) {
        return (T)c.getAnnotation(annotation);
    }

    public static <T> T getAnnotation(Class c, String fieldName, Class<? extends T> annotation) {
        try {
            Field f = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName); 
            return (T)f.getAnnotation(annotation);   // compile error here??
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(nsfe);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Field.getAnnotation` expects a class which is a subclass of annotation:

```
public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass) {
```

therefore in your helper method you need to restrict your type parameter accordingly:

```
public static <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<?> c, String fieldName, Class<T> annotation) {
```

Note that the same holds for your class level helper method. But you used a raw type `Class c` which prevented the compiler to issue the same error.